# Entity Framework: Can't save data because of tracking

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I have got a complex class. Feedback and Steps. I am using SQL database and .NET Core 2. I can save main properties but can't save the sub class `FeedbackSteps` properties

```
public class FeedbackModel
{
    [Key]
    public int FeedBackID { get; set; }
    public DateTime FBDate { get; set; }
    public bool? VideoStatus { get; set; }
    public string VideoDetail { get; set; }
    public string PITFeedBack { get; set; }
    public int ActivityID { get; set; }
    public virtual ActivityModel Activity { get; set; }
    public int ClientID { get; set; }
    public virtual ClientModel Client { get; set; }
    public int? SupportPlanID { get; set; }
    public virtual SupportPlanModel SupportPlan { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public bool FeedbackStatus { get; set; } = true;

    virtual public List<FeedbackStepModel> FeedbackSteps { get; set; }
}

public class FeedbackStepModel
{
    [Key]
    public int FeedbackStepID { get; set; }
    public int FeedbackID { get; set; } = 0;
    public int SupportPlanID { get; set; }    
    public int StepNumber { get; set; }
    public string StepDetail { get; set; }
    public string AchievementStatus { get; set; }
    public string AchievementComment { get; set; }
}
```

This is the post method. View returns Edited or Updated feedback and i just want to update the database with new data

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Edit(FeedbackModel feedback)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            feedbackRepository.Save(feedback);
            TempData["message"] = $"Feedback has been saved";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

After EDIT, I would like to save it...

```
    public void Save(FeedbackModel feedback)
    {
        if (feedback.FeedBackID == 0)
        {
            context.FeedbackModels.Add(feedback);
        }
        else
        {
            FeedbackModel dbEntry = context.FeedbackModels.Include(s => s.FeedbackSteps).FirstOrDefault(a => a.FeedBackID == feedback.FeedBackID);

            if (dbEntry != null)
            {
                dbEntry.FeedBackID = feedback.FeedBackID;
                dbEntry.FBDate = feedback.FBDate;
                dbEntry.VideoStatus = feedback.VideoStatus;
                dbEntry.VideoDetail = feedback.VideoDetail;
                dbEntry.SupportPlanID = feedback.SupportPlanID;
                dbEntry.ActivityID = feedback.ActivityID;
                dbEntry.PITFeedBack = feedback.PITFeedBack;
                dbEntry.ClientID = feedback.ClientID;
                dbEntry.EmployeeID = feedback.EmployeeID;                   
                dbEntry.FeedbackStatus = feedback.FeedbackStatus;
                dbEntry.FeedbackSteps = feedback.FeedbackSteps;
            }
        }

        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

But I get this error all the time

> The instance of entity type 'FeedbackStepModel' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{FeedbackStepID: 1}' is already being tracked.
>
> When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

Comment: If you read your feedback model from the database, it is *already* being tracked; no need to add it to the DataContext.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - but then the Id wouldn't be `0`

Comment: @AliAzra, Where is your new `FeedbackSteps` that coming on POST?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: Come again?  That's what you *want* on an edit.

Comment: Yes it is coming from Post

Comment: Robert Harvey. I didn't understand. if I delete "dbEntry.FeedbackSteps = feedback.FeedbackSteps;" this, than it save to database without new data.. How i suppose to update the old data without assign the value

Comment: @AliAzra - can you indicate on which line this happens? And what the valu of `feedback.FeedBackID` then is?

Comment: @RobertHarvey - you can't update w/o a valid Id. Maybe read that Save() method again?

Comment: So the nested FeedbackStepModels are already in the database - maybe you just need to attach them? Are any of the nested FeedbackStepModels new also or do they all already exist in the database?

Comment: @AliAzra What is your ASP.NET Core project version? Is it ASP.NET Core 2.0 or higher? Please confirm this.

Comment: First of all thanks for all help, It is Core 2.0 and feedback.FeedbackID = 0.. I change the ID to 1 but error is the same error. FeedbackStepID issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `FeedbackModel` update operation with children (`FeedbackSteps`) should be as follows:

```
FeedbackModel dbEntry = context.FeedbackModels.Include(s => s.FeedbackSteps).FirstOrDefault(a => a.FeedBackID == feedback.FeedBackID);

if (dbEntry != null)
{
      dbEntry.FeedBackID = feedback.FeedBackID;
      dbEntry.FBDate = feedback.FBDate;
      dbEntry.VideoStatus = feedback.VideoStatus;
      dbEntry.VideoDetail = feedback.VideoDetail;
      dbEntry.SupportPlanID = feedback.SupportPlanID;
      dbEntry.ActivityID = feedback.ActivityID;
      dbEntry.PITFeedBack = feedback.PITFeedBack;
      dbEntry.ClientID = feedback.ClientID;
      dbEntry.EmployeeID = feedback.EmployeeID;                   
      dbEntry.FeedbackStatus = feedback.FeedbackStatus;

      dbEntry.FeedbackSteps.Clear(); // First you have to clear the existing feedBackSteps

      foreach(FeedbackStep feedBackStep in feedback.FeedbackSteps)
      {
         dbEntry.FeedbackSteps.Add(feedBackStep); // You have to add new and updated feedBackStep here.
      }
}
```

If `dbEntry.FeedbackSteps.Clear();` does not work (may be in EF Core 2.0 or lower `Clear()` does not work) then replace `dbEntry.FeedbackSteps.Clear();` with the following code:

```
foreach(FeedbackStep feedbackStepToBeRemoved in dbEntry.FeedbackSteps)
{
   context.Remove(feedbackStepToBeRemoved);
}
```

Comment: Thank you TanvirArjel. I tried but gave me the exactly same error again.

Comment: Well done Tanvir. It is working now.. Thanks a lot.. One more question. I have got similar datamodel with same database and website. Also coding is  exactly the same code, but some how it is working. I am going to post it that code with new question. Please if you have time look at it and tell me why it is working there but not here.

Comment: @AliAzra Great to hear that. Sure! mention me after posting the question.

Comment: Thank you, I typed but i need to wait 90min to post.

Comment: Okay! Then I have to see this in the morning (my time) because its already 12.09 AM in my country.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188191/discussion-between-tanvirarjel-and-aliazra).